# RStudio Scatter plot Error: unexpected symbol in "Scatter plot

Tags: r

I doing an exerise on RStudio [https://www.slideshare.net/thoi_gian/iris-data-analysis-with-r][1]

tried below command im getting Error: unexpected symbol in "Scatter plot"

Scatter plot plot(iris, col=iris$Species) legend(7,4.3,unique(iris$Species),col=1:length(iris$Species),p ch=1) Lattice library Ggplot2 library

Answer (score 0):

You have copied too much text from the slideshare slide, and as a result you are getting the error because that is not proper syntax.  The following should work:

```
data(iris)
plot(iris, col=iris$Species)
```

Comment: is the second line another command which is different from the first @Eric

Comment: @dwayne yes.  the first line loads the dataset iris which is installed by default with the R application.  The second line, which is another command, plots the data.  I found this document pretty easy to read and very helpful when first getting started:  https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf